# Problems with exported GPX track

Tags: gps, export, gpx, garmin

I tried to export a track as GPX for my Garmin using QGIS. Here you can see the result:
[image]

The original Track is saved as PostGIS multiline. I exported the track by "Save As" -> GPX, WGS84 (default options).

Whats the reason for that and whats the right way to export a multiline as GPX?

Comment: Have you stopped recording the track at some locations and continued later?

Comment: No, it' s not a GPS-written GPX track. It's exported from a PostGIS Multiline (created with QGIS).

Comment: Thus your multiline has several parts? Multiline does not specify any order for the parts and A-B-C is as valid as A-C-B. I would have a try with merging the multilinestring into one linestring before export. But that succeeds only if the endpoints and startpoints of the parts match.

Comment: You'll likely need to split the track into the three (or however many) pieces, as @user30184 commented, a multipart only works successfully if the end points match.

Comment: Yes, the multi line consists of several merged parts with different directions. That is the reason for that 'zig-zag'. I have a lot GPX to export -  so how could I correct them without spending too much time?

Comment: Is it OK to manage them again as separate parts? Then you could use ST_Dump http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Dump.html.

Comment: I’m unable to replicate this; I imported a multi-segment GPX into PostGIS (multilinestring), viewed in QGIS, saved-as GPX again then viewed in QGIS, and the individual segments aren’t joined as in your example. Could you share data?